# Catching the abort in a WebMethod when calling XHR.abort()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Summary: I would like to be able to catch the XHR.abort() in a WebMethod to stop executing server-side code as soon as possible.

I have a webmethod, similar as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetHello()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return "{\"result\":\"Hello!\"}";
}
```

On the page I call this method with the following javascript (jQuery) code:

```
var lastXHR = null;

function doCall() {

    if (lastXHR != null)
        lastXHR.abort();

    lastXHR = $.ajax({
        url: "default.aspx/GetHello",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'POST',
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (textStatus.statusText == "abort") {
                // I know this was aborted here
                // Code omitted for simplicity
            }
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var d = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            alert(d.result);
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            lastXHR = null;
        }
    });
}
```

I am able to handle the `abort()` quite easily with this code on the client, but I would like the web server to stop executing `GetHello()` when the XHR is aborted.

The reason I need to do this is because on the server side in my project I am calling a search on a database, which can potentially take many seconds to complete, and calling [`SqlCommand.Cancel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx) would be very beneficial to my IT team ;-)

UPDATE: I'm going to try calling a secondary WebMethod whose sole purpose is to indicate that the previous call from the same client is to be cancelled. Will post this as an answer if it works.

Other ways to do this would be much-appreciated though!